# quotation marks in a python function

Tags: python, function, variables

I am writing a function for anova test in python, so the analysis will work for any dependent and independent variables. Something like this -

```
def oneway_anova(df, dep_var, indep_var):
    mod = ols('dep_var ~ indep_var',data=an).fit()
    aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod, typ=2)
```

However, when I call the function, like this -

```
oneway_anova(df, 'hours_growth', 'pesticide')
```

the dep_var and indep_var in this line

```
mod = ols('dep_var ~ indep_var',data=an).fit()
```

are not getting replaced. I am guessing that this is because the model needs quotations in the syntax to work, but since I am giving the names separately within quotes, it is not working. What I would like to see is to get this line of code read as, but I want to do this in a function with input variables:

```
mod = ols('hours_growth ~ pesticide',data=an).fit()
```

Can someone help me with how I can do this?

Comment: You need to use "f-strings": `mod = ols(f'{dep_var} ~ {indep_var}',data=an).fit()`

Comment: that doesnt work. I believe that it is because the resolution then becomes mod = ols(''hours_growth' ~ 'pesticide'',data=an).fit(), where as it will only work when resolved as mod = ols('hours_growth ~ pesticide',data=an).fit()

Comment: Don't provide quotes. Or, if it is not possible, use `replace` function to get rid of the quites: `mod = ols(f'{dep_var} ~ {indep_var}'.replace("'", ""), data=an).fit()` to get rid of the quotes

Comment: I tried again and your first answer worked!. If you would like to submit this as an answer, I would be happy to accept it. Thanks a lot